# Search emails in Microsoft Exchange/EWS/Office 365

Tags: rest, soap, office365, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

We would like to query our Exchange server for emails based on (for example) the Subject field. Not from a specific address or to a specific address, but rather all emails "that went through the server" and the term X appeared in the subject.
Preferably some standard way like REST / SOAP and so on with HTTPS. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options I think, at least with powershell. First and fastest is to do a messagetrace using get-transportservice | get-messagetrackinglog to see what messages have been received and sent.
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa997573(v=exchg.160).aspx

Other would be to search every mailbox for messages conforming to a pre-set filter. You could use get-mailbox | search-mailbox for that.
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd298173(v=exchg.160).aspx

Answer (score 0):

eDiscovery is the most common method you would use to do that https://support.office.com/en-us/article/eDiscovery-in-Office-365-143b3ab8-8cb0-4036-a5fc-6536d837bfce . You can use ediscovery is EWS (SOAP) https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj190897(v=exchg.150).aspx the REST API's in Office365 also allow you to search at the folder level https://msdn.microsoft.com/office/office365/APi/mail-rest-operations